# Pandas - Reading HTML

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to convert [this](http://www.scb.se/sv_/Hitta-statistik/Statistik-efter-amne/Befolkning/Befolkningens-sammansattning/Befolkningsstatistik/25788/25795/Helarsstatistik---Riket/26046/) table into a `pandas` `DataFrame`

I have done the following so far

```
import pandas as pd

url = 'http://www.scb.se/sv_/Hitta-statistik/Statistik-efter-amne/Befolkning/Befolkningens-sammansattning/Befolkningsstatistik/25788/25795/Helarsstatistik---Riket/26046/'

df = pd.read_html(url,thousands=' ')
df2= df[0]
```

My problem here is that `pandas` do not recognize that the index value `0` are the headers. I also want the column value `År` to be the index value.

Lastly, I would like to plot the `Folkmängd` column values as `Y` and the `År` values as `X`, in a line-plot.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `index_col=0` if you want Ar as the index, `pd.read_html(url,thousands=' ',index_col=0)` looks pretty much exactly as it does in the table bar the thousands seperator

Comment: Thanks, i also added df = pd.read_html(url,thousands=' ',index_col=0,header=0) which made the table exactly as i wanted it. Is there a way to tell pandas that the 'År' column is years and not numbers

Comment: You might want `pd.read_html(url,thousands=' ',index_col=0, header=0)` if you want to use the column names

Comment: I don't think it matters with the years,  you have no dates so all you have are numbers. `parse_dates=0` would make every year the `year-01-01` but I don't see any advantage

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be close to what you want:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
matplotlib.style.use('ggplot')

url = 'http://www.scb.se/sv_/Hitta-statistik/Statistik-efter-amne/Befolkning/Befolkningens-sammansattning/Befolkningsstatistik/25788/25795/Helarsstatistik---Riket/26046/'

table = pd.read_html(url,thousands=' ', header=0, index_col=0)[0]
table["Folkmängd"].plot(color='k')
plt.show()
```

Which should give you something like:

[image]